# Array Of Objects Returns Undefined When Accessing Members

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to access an array from an array of objects that I passing as props into a stateless component. For instance, here is the scenario:

```
const compA = props => {
  return (
     //other code
     console.log('CompA Arr: ', props.Arr)
     //I can clearly see the Array here before passing it as props
     <CompB props={props.Arr} />
  );

}
export default compA;

const compB = props => {
  return (
     //other code
     console.log('CompA Arr: ', props.Arr)
     //I can clearly see the Array now here, but below is undefined
     <input type="text" value={props && props[0].person && props[0].person[0].name}
  );

}
export default compB;
```

If you console.log props.Arr, here's a sample of the array of the objects

```
props:[{...}]
//props expanded
0:
  id: 1
  position: "manager"
  person: [{...}]

//person expanded
0:
  name: "John Doe"
  age:  "40"
```

I am trying to access the name field in person array, however, this returns an error of "Cannot read property of 'person' of undefined. What am I missing? I can clearly see the array of objects in both components but I cannot access their members.

Comment: You are logging `props.Arr` but try to access `props[0]` ?

Comment: I tried that as well, but that is undefined. If I were to hover to the Person Object, the console shows that to access it, you need to do props[0]

Comment: @usr41059 If possible could you share the value of ```console.log('CompA Arr: ', props.Arr)```. That might help to solve your problem.

Comment: @SDushan here's the output


props:[{...}]
addressKey: "employee"
required:true

and if I expand the props object, the output is the same as above.